# Truly virtual FTP

Tags: database, ftp, cdn

I am looking to set up an FTP server without connecting it to a file system.

I want to use a database to store which of the many large files on my site each user will have access to. Because of the number and size of the files involved, the files cannot all be stored on a single server so a link based setup is not useful.

I am imagining an FTP server that will act as a pass-through for a backend CDN that stores all the files and checks a remote database for which files to present.

Does a system like this exist? If it doesn't exist, Which open source FTP server would be easiest to modify to suit my needs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at JScape?
It costs money but has the capability

Comment: I just checked their documentation, and couldn't find what I wanted. I'm checking up with them some more to be sure. Do you have any more specific information about enabling this using JScape?

Comment: Sure, Jscape can use 'triggers'. when a file is uploaded a triggered action can be used to insert it as a blob into a database. Conversely if a file download request is recieved you would need to

Comment: Be warned, you will need to code - Conversely if a file download request is received you would need to write an action to retrieve it from the database before allowing it to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on StackOverflow, I assume that you are ready for coding. In this case you can use FTP/FTPS server component, included in [FTPSBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-ftps.php) of our SecureBlackbox product. It lets you handle all operations yourself, so you are not bound to the file system in any way.

We also have [SFTP server](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-sftp.php) (SSH File Transfer Protocol) with similar design.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into using your product.